# Is it possible to use a timestamp for several flatten tables in BigQuery?

Tags: timestamp, google-bigquery, flatten

I would like to know if it is possible to query a flatten table with a specific timestamp function similar to a similar request:
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([89571105.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-02-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-02-10')).

Is it also possible to create query several flatten tables with a timestamp function?

If so, could you please share an example.

Comment: What is a "flatten table"? What is the query that you are trying to run?

Comment: Dear Elliot; when i'm talking about flatten tables, this means that BigQuery  takes a repeated fields and creates one row of results for each value of the repeated field (with all other fields duplicated).GROUP BY expression clauses implicitly flatten queried data.

Comment: Could you pseudo type the query on a public table you want even if it's not accurate? It's hard to understand what you want, and there might be features for it.

Comment: SELECT
  date,
  customDimensions.value,
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  device.deviceCategory,
FROM
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20160703], customDimensions.value )), 
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20160704], customDimensions.value )), 
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20160705], customDimensions.value )),  
  (FLATTEN([85801771.ga_sessions_20160706], customDimensions.value )),
  WHERE
 hits.type = 'EVENT'
GROUP BY
  date,
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  hits.page.pageTitle,
  customDimensions.value
ORDER BY date
LIMIT
  100000

Comment: @ Pentium10 Here's an extrapolation with a public samples tables: SELECT
  DATE, 
  SourceCommonName ,
  Themes,
  customDimensions.value,
  Persons,
  Organizations

FROM
  (FLATTEN([gdelt-bq:internetarchivebooks.2008notxt], customDimensions.value )), 
  (FLATTEN([gdelt-bq:internetarchivebooks.2009notxt], customDimensions.value )), 
  WHERE
  BookMeta_Year = 2008
  AND BookMeta_Language = EN
GROUP BY
  DATE, 
  SourceCommonName ,
  Themes,
  customDimensions.value,
  Persons,
  Organizations
ORDER BY date
LIMIT
  100000

Comment: Unfortunately there's no custom dimensions values in that tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross products with repeated fields are easier to express using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/). Try this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  customDimension.value,
  visitNumber,
  visitId,
  device.deviceCategory
FROM `85801771.ga_sessions_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) AS customDimension
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20160703' AND '20160706' AND
  hit.type = 'EVENT'
GROUP BY date, visitNumber, visitId, hit.page.pageTitle, customDimension.value
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 100000;
```

You can run it over the sample table in the `LondonCycleHelmet` dataset:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  date,
  customDimension.value,
  visitNumber,
  visitId
FROM `google.com:analytics-bigquery.LondonCycleHelmet.ga_sessions_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) AS customDimension
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hit
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20130910' AND '20130910' AND
  hit.type = 'EVENT'
GROUP BY date, visitNumber, visitId, hit.page.pageTitle, customDimension.value
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 100000;
```

Comment: Thank you Ellott; your help was very much appreciated